# How can I run the different flavors using flutter_flavor package?

Tags: flutter, flutter-packages

I want to create dev mode and prod mode for my app. In Flutter's documentation about flavors, they refer to two packages on `pub.dev` and a bunch of articles. The [flutter_flavor](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_flavor) package seemed the easiest to implement so I installed it and I followed the steps mentioned in their documentation. However, I don't know how to actually run the different flavors? It is not mentioned in the package's documentation. They mention adding some configurations to `launch.json` but I'm not sure what that does and how am I supposed to use it when running the app? Is there a command to run the flavors from the vscode terminal?

The steps I did:

1. create two main files; `main_prod.dart` and `main_dev.dart`
2. inside `main_dev.dart`:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_flavor/flutter_flavor.dart';
import 'main.dart';

void main() {
  FlavorConfig(
    name: "DEV",
    color: Colors.red,
    location: BannerLocation.topStart,
    variables: {
      "baseUrl": "https://www.example2.com",
      "appTitle": "app1-dev",
    },
  );
  return runApp(MyApp());
}
```

inside `main_prod.dart`:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_flavor/flutter_flavor.dart';
import 'main.dart';

void main() {
  FlavorConfig(
    color: Colors.red,
    location: BannerLocation.topStart,
    variables: {
      "baseUrl": "https://www.example2.com",
      "appTitle": "app1-dev",
    },
  );
  return runApp(MyApp());
}
```

3. my `launch.json`:

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "skinhealthapp",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart"
        },
        {
            "name": "PROD-Flavor",
            "program": "[project-folder]/lib/main_prod.dart",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart"
        },
        {
            "name": "DEV-Flavor",
            "program": "[project-folder]/lib/main_dev.dart",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then what?